# Extracting values from one raster based on condition in another raster and distinguished by polygons in a vector file

Tags: if-statement, extract, polygon, raster, terra

I have one raster file on land cover (30x30m pixels), one raster file on soil organic carbon (SOC) (250x250m pixels), and one vector file with contiguous polygons of different sizes.

What I require is a mean SOC value for each polygon. But only based on pixels that have a select land cover, here grassland.

I first made sure that the two raster files have the same extent and resolution, so I scaled the SOC map to 30x30m. I then turned the vector map into a SpatRaster (perhaps not needed), and realised that the extent is slightly different from the two raster files (the vector file when loaded into R has a 'bounding box' rather than extent, perhaps it relates to that). I also stacked the land cover and SOC files.

I am stuck here now. First, I am not sure whether it is an issue that the vector file has a different extent, and if so, how to align it with the raster files. Second, I am not sure whether I had to to convert the vector file to a SpatRaster in the first place, or if keeping it as a vector file is just fine. Third, what code could I use to now extract the mean SOC values for grassland for each polygon (i.e. a conditional if clause).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some example data

```
library(terra)
pols <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
carbon <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
names(carbon) <- "carbon"
landuse <- round(carbon/100)
```

Here is a solution. Assuming that grassland has value "3" in `landuse`

```
grass <- subst(landuse, 3, 1, others=NA)
grass_carbon <- mask(carbon, grass)
e <- extract(grass_carbon, pols, mean, na.rm=TRUE, ID=FALSE)
data.frame(pols$NAME_2, e)
#        pols.NAME_2   carbon
#1          Clervaux 344.6667
#2          Diekirch 305.2462
#3           Redange 300.0202
#4           Vianden 295.0000
#5             Wiltz 329.2917
#6        Echternach 312.9183
#7            Remich 281.1053
#8      Grevenmacher 294.5238
#9          Capellen 321.3462
#10 Esch-sur-Alzette 300.4255
#11       Luxembourg 299.0872
#12           Mersch 301.0226
```

This is good enough if differences in cell sizes within polygons are relatively small. Otherwise, you could use `zonal` with cell sizes as weights. You could also use that if the land cover classes were expressed as fractions of the grid cells.

To plot the results, you can do

```
pols$carbon <- e
plot(pols, "carbon")
```

Comment: Thanks! I got this error (Error: [mask] extents do not match), despite having clipped both rasters in ArcGIS earlier based on the same shape file outline. I tried  mask(crop(carbon, ext(grass)), grass)  but get the same error message.

Comment: The geometries have to match. The extent after cropping depends on the input raster as you can only cut off entire rows and columns. You may need to use `resample`.

Comment: Hello Robert, and thanks. Got through your code.  I just wonder, why do we use 'sum' in  e <- extract(grass_carbon, pols, sum, na.rm=TRUE, ID=FALSE) ? Should it be mean, to get the average SOC value by polygon?

Comment: yes, of course, I have fixed that.

Comment: Great, thanks ... for a better understanding, are we only including cells that are 100% grassland, or any cell that has any amount of grassland?

Comment: In the example a cell is either grassland or not.

Comment: For some time I had the problem of only getting SOC values for a subset of the polygons. It seems the issue was due to me aligning the extent of the two rasters. Aligning the dimension instead seems fine.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. Is it possible to adjust the subst() code, so that only pixels with a select amount (%) of grassland are being considered?