# Extracting pixel values based on condition

Tags: if-statement, vector, raster, r-sf, terra

I have one raster file on land cover (30x30m pixels), one raster file on soil organic carbon (SOC) (250x250m pixels), and one vector file with contiguous polygons of different sizes.

What I require is a mean SOC value for each polygon, based on pixels whose landcover includes at least 60% grassland.

There are two related posts, i.e.
[Extracting values from one raster based on condition in another raster and distinguished by polygons in a vector file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75655208/extracting-values-from-one-raster-based-on-condition-in-another-raster-and-disti/75657641#75657641) and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/454539/extracting-values-from-one-raster-based-on-condition-in-another-raster-and-disti/454549?noredirect=1#comment742156_454549 which work really well. I am uncertain how to adjust either one of these conditional statements (1) ifel(lulc == 3, 1, NA) or (2) subst(landuse, 3, 1, others=NA) to only consider pixels with a minimum amount (%) of grassland.

The current code only distinguishes whether a cell is grassland or not. That means, grassland may only account for a small amount of the land use in the cell. The carbon value allocated to the cell is based on dominant land use, however, which could be annual cropland or forest, with quite different SOC values compared to actual grassland.

Here is an example code, that was earlier suggested by @Robert Hijmans:

```
library(terra)
pols <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
carbon <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
names(carbon) <- "carbon"
landuse <- round(carbon/100)

grass <- subst(landuse, 3, 1, others=NA)
grass_carbon <- mask(carbon, grass)
e <- extract(grass_carbon, pols, mean, na.rm=TRUE, ID=FALSE)
data.frame(pols$NAME_2, e)

pols$carbon <- e
plot(pols, "carbon")
```

Just to add. Because in my actual research problem the two rasters have different pixel sizes, I had to first unify their dimensions and resolutions, for which I used code like:

```
g <- terra::resample(carbon,landuse, method = 'near')
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example* At a minimum we need to know what the raster geometries are, so at least `show()` the data you are using. It would seem more sensible to only consider grid cells that *are* grassland.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. Do you mean cells that are entirely grassland?